# Windows Store App shows black screen

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, modern-ui

I have a problem with my Windows Store App Car Buddy. Microsoft Support contacted me about a problem with my app, that it shows only a black screen instead of actual content. I am unable to reproduce the error, although I tried on several computers that are available to me.

But the problem has been also brought to my attention by users, and honestly I have no idea what is the reason. There are no errors, the app does not crash, apparently while in black screen users can still access Settings Charm and pages that are available from there.

Can you help? If you need additional information just ask. I am clueless atm...

**UPDATE 31.05.2013: It seems that while navigating from ExtendedSplashScreen to first page, the Frame.Navigate method returns false, and no exception is thrown. Any ideas how to debug this? Or force the exception to show?**

Comment: Does it black screen on startup or suddenly while the app is open?

Comment: Black screen is shown on startup. Nothing else is visible before.

Comment: I see the same problem with my application and can't find solution. Have you found anything more? The bad thing is that it is not reproducible when debugger is attached. Only when running without debugger.

Comment: Check all the warnings given by Visual Studio. I've found my answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. The problem was the lack of some Resource translations in default language.

Answer (score 0):

I seen the same problem with my application. It was only reproducible when running without debugger. So, I ended with using MessageDialog to determine the place where application fails. 
It was the ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED exception at attempt to access clipboard when loading application. So, I wrapped clipboard operation into try/catch and now it works.
There are 2 strange(bad) things:

- after loading the application the clipboard operations just work, so you
  can't expect such type of exception;
- this exception is never shown to end-user and application is not terminated - it just shows blank screen.

I suppose, you have something of this kind, maybe not clipboard..